# Stop the accidentally typed in bash command that is not yet executed but would immediately overwrite files after a long ongoing process?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line

Basically I am running some bash process in MobaX terminal which takes maybe 20 hours to generate the files and I was thinking of typing another bash command that will take place right after this bash process that likely will finish in middle of overnight. So I typed in another command and entered but it is not executed yet since there is already an ongoing process. Then I realized that it might overwrite the files while I am sleeping. Is there a way to cancel that typed in command without stopping the 20 hours long ongoing process?

Comment: Is there anything against simply CTRL+C in the terminal to stop the command from executing? Or are you trying to kill the process?

Comment: SO is not the right place to ask questions like this. http://superuser.com or [unix.se] would be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type CTRL+Z to suspend the running process and then `fg` to resume it. That will have the side-effect of flushing the shell's input queue.